# What parameter to pass to Proj4Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

I need to use https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet for my case.

I have **EPSG:32638**

But I don't know what parameter to pass to constructor. From the web site
it has example:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2400',
  '+lon_0=15.808277777799999 +lat_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +x_0=1500000.0 ' +
  '+y_0=0.0 +proj=tmerc +ellps=bessel +units=m ' +
  '+towgs84=414.1,41.3,603.1,-0.855,2.141,-7.023,0 +no_defs',
  {
    resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048] // 3 example zoom level resolutions
  }
);
```

I am confused about the **second** and **third** parameters, what should they be?
Also once I pass this CRS to my map, can it mess up my map? (It has already many features which I implemented with Leaflet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spatialreference.org](https://spatialreference.org/) to find information about any coordinate system, such as [EPSG:32638](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32638/). On that page, click the Proj4 link:

[image]

And you will have your second parameter:

```
+proj=utm +zone=38 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_de
```

As for the resolutions, it should probably work by not changing them, or by not using them at all. The documentation states:

> resolutions - an array of resolutions (projected coordinate units per pixel) for each corresponding zoom level; default is to use Leaflet's native resolutions. You should use scales or resolutions, not both.

Since it is an option you could omit it and go with the default, making your code as short as this:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:32638',
  '+proj=utm +zone=38 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_de'
);
```

Comment: Thanks I followed your advice but now I am getting this error: https://ibb.co/k9hhD4K

Comment: Above error is likely caused by this: `L.map(.../*ommitted*/..).setView([42.110449, 44.005737], 8)`

Comment: Maybe you have to add the resolutions after all: `{resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048]}`

Comment: Did that but still getting this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65626019/uncaught-typeerror-coordinates-must-be-finite-numbers

Comment: You must declare as many resolution as there are zoom levels you'll be using. For zoom level 8 you must have 9 resolutions, since first zoom level is 0. As @BritishSteel cited docs, resolutions must reflect projected units per pixel for corresponding zoom levels of your actual layer you'll be using.

Comment: @TomazicM I don't know what values to specify in resolutions, can you suggest some?  How do I know what values to specify in resolutions?

Comment: Do you have any info about actual map/layer you'll be using? Is it raster or vector layer?

Comment: @TomazicM It is WMS layer, vector

Comment: If you look at projection info at https://epsg.io/32638, you'll see that minX is 166021.44 and maxX is 534994.66, which gives you width of 368973.22. If you divide this by 256, you'll get resolution at zoom 0. For each next resolution just divide previous one by 2.